# Problem adding new sticker on my canvas - Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, canvas

I am developing a drawing application where the user can also insert a text sticker with the text they want. For this, when the user selects the text sticker, an AlertDialog appears, where he types the text. When inserting the first text there are no problems. The problem arises when the user already has a sticker and is going to add a new one. When the sticker is added to the canvas, all other stickers disappear, leaving only the new one. However, if the user double-clicks on the new sticker, or once outside the new sticker and clicks inside, the stickers reappear in their proper locations.

I already did a test, where I generate sticker defaults with the same name outside the alertDialog, with just a press of any button, and the stickers are added correctly without the others disappearing. In other words, my stickers just don't work when I use alertDialog. I've already run and I can't find the error. Can someone help me?

MainActivity:

```
text.setOnClickListener { 
        showAlertDialogSticker() 
}

//Change text color dialog box
private fun showAlertDialogSticker() {
    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
    val layoutView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_sticker, null)

    checkBold = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio_bold)
    checkItalic = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio_italic)
    checkSublime = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio_sublime)
    pickedColorSticker = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.pickedColorSticker)
    txtSticker = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sticker)
    sticker = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.sticker)
    multiColorPickerSticker = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.multiColorPickerSticker)

    multiColorPickerSticker.setInitialColor(0x7F313C93)
    multiColorPickerSticker.subscribe { color: Int, _: Boolean, _: Boolean ->
        pickedColorSticker.setBackgroundColor(color)
        sticker.setTextColor(color)
        textColor = color
    }

    dialogButtonCancel = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel)
    dialogButtonAdd = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.btnSave)

    dialogBuilder.setView(layoutView)
    dialogAdd = dialogBuilder.create()
    dialogAdd.window?.attributes?.windowAnimations ?: R.style.DialogAnimation
    dialogAdd.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    dialogAdd.show()

    dialogButtonCancel.setOnClickListener {
        dialogAdd.cancel()
    }

    dialogButtonAdd.setOnClickListener {
        //Add text sticker
        validFiel()
        if (isValid) {
            my_canvas.addTextSticker(textStick, textColor, null)
            dialogAdd.dismiss()
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Using the code above I have the problem reported. Calling the method as below, it was possible to add several stickers without problems.

```
text.setOnClickListener {
     my_canvas.addTextSticker(textStick, textColor, null)
}
```